# What is the proper way to use tkinter wait_variable()?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I have a block of code like this:

```
    def engine_input_number_of_students_and_student_information(self, window):
        self.__input.input_number_of_students(self, window)
        print(self.number_of_students)
```

and the function `input_number_of_students()` was defined in class Input as below:

```
class Input:
    # Function to ask user to input number of student.
    # Print error and force the user to re-input if wrong data is given.
    def input_number_of_students(self, engine, window):
        sub = tk.Toplevel(master=window)
        sub.title("Number of students")
        sub.resizable(height=False, width=False)
        window.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {str(sub)} center')
        frm1 = tk.Frame(master=sub)
        frm1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        lbl = tk.Label(text="Enter number of students:", master=frm1)
        number_of_students_var = tk.StringVar()
        ent = tk.Entry(width=3, master=frm1, textvariable=number_of_students_var)
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
        ent.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
        frm2 = tk.Frame(master=sub)
        frm2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)

        def ok():
            try:
                number_of_students = int(number_of_students_var.get())
                if number_of_students < 0:
                    messagebox.showerror(message="Error: number of students must be non-negative")
                    ent.delete(-1, tk.END)
                else:
                    engine.number_of_students = number_of_students
                    sub.destroy()
            except:
                messagebox.showerror(message="Invalid number of students")

        ok_btn = tk.Button(text="OK", master=frm2, command=lambda: ok)
        ok_btn.pack(ipadx=5)
        ok_btn.wait_variable(number_of_students_var)
```

which basically create a sub-window with an entry and a button OK. The user input the value in the entry, and press OK, that value will be stored in `engine.number_of_students`. But when I try to run this, function `print(self.number_of_students)` was executed right when I input some value in the entry and I didn't even press the button (it prints 0, obviously).

I also tried to replace `number_of_students_var` by `engine.number_of_students`, it stucks  there forever!

Well I read that the `wait_variable()` will wait until the value of the parameter we pass into it is modified, then carry out the function, so the problem I'm having is... kinda make sense. But I feel that I don't truly understand this function and how to use it properly (like, what will wait for the modification of the parameter?) , so could you propose other ways to perform what I have described?

Comment: Using `wait_variable()` in this case is not appropriate.  Use `wait_window()` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 could you please propose a more detailed way? I still cannot really imagine how we're gonna use the wait_window()

Comment: Try replacing the `wait_variable()` line by `sub.wait_window(sub)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Well it does not close the sub-window when I press OK. It stays there forever.

Comment: @acw1668 Bro, with your solution, and I removed the ```lambda``` in the ```command=lambda: ok``` and it worked! Thank you very much! By the way, can you explain how the ```lambda``` thing means and how does it work? I just know that it's an anonymous function, but I don't understand precisely how it performs and how it works.

Comment: Should be `lambda: ok()` if using `lambda`.  But since `ok()` takes no argument, it is not necessary to use `lambda` in this case.

Comment: using `lambda` in such case would be the same as `def func():` and then `your_func()` and then using like `command=func`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait_variable` waits for a variable to change. Because the variable you are waiting on is associated with an `Entry` widget, whenever you type in the entry widget the variable will instantly change. `wait_variable` senses this change and returns.

If you want to use `wait_variable` in this situation,  you do *not* want to associate the variable with the entry widget. Instead, you would set the variable when the user presses the "ok" button. However, you have a separate problem which is that `ok` is never called because of how you've defined the button.

You're using `lambda` for the button, and inside the `lambda` which does `ok`. However, `ok` does not call `ok`, it simply refers to it. To call the function you need to do `ok()`. However, in this case, there's no need to use `lambda` at all. The button requires a callable, so you can directly pass `ok`:

```
ok_btn = tk.Button(text="OK", master=frm2, command=ok)
```

Now, back to waiting on the variable. You need to do the following:

- remove the definition of `textvariable` when defining the entry widget (eg:   `ent = tk.Entry(width=3, master=frm1)`)
- have `ok` do `ent.get()` rather than `number_of_students_var.get()` since the entry widget is no longer directly associated with the entry widget.
- have `ok` set the variable `number_of_students_var`, which will trigger `wait_variable` to return